# How do i loop a function

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript at the moment and i want to ask you about an exercise that i'm trying to finish. This is the quiz i should finish:

https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud803/lessons/a7c5b540-51a6-44dc-b2f2-515c9dd6ca4f/concepts/c746623a-eefd-4518-9890-2c5f320b0282
and here is my code. I just dont understand what im doing wrong . can someone explain me.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script>

function makeLine(length) {
    var line = "";
    for (var j = 1; j <= length; j++) {
       line += "* ";
    }
    return line + "\n";
 }

 function buildTriangle(widest) {      
    var x = makeLine(1);
    while(x <= widest){
       return x;
        x++;
    }
 }

 document.write(buildTriangle(10));

 </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I would like to know what i did wrong and how i can fix it, because i always get either "undefined" or nothing at all.
Also i know it's probably a simple mistake but i'm still a beginner so.

Comment: When you once return from the function, the function is done at that point, the execution won't go back to the loop in the function.

Answer (score 0):

after a return statement, any instruction never executed

Answer (score 0):

change your function to this

```
function buildTriangle(widest) {      
    var x = makeLine(1);
    while(x <= widest){
           // putting return here would make function execution to stop 
           // and return the value to the callee, thus not executing 
           // any statement after this.
       x++;//this making this an unreachable code
    }
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues in function buildTriangle(widest).

var x = makeLine(1);

This will always set x to makeLine(1) doing x++ in the while loop will do nothing.

Further more the x++ is after a return statement so the code will never reach it.

Hope this helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

It's how you actually write the `*` on your `document`. I've modified how your `buildTriangle` works and kept `makeLine` intact.

```js
(function() {
    function makeLine(length) {
        var line = "";
        for (var j = 1; j <= length; j++) {
           line += "* ";
        }
        return line + "<br/>";
     }
     
     function buildTriangle(widest) {
        for(var x = 1; x <= widest; x++){
            // Moved write inside the loop
            // since you want to write each line here
            document.write(makeLine(x));
        }
     }

     buildTriangle(10);
})();
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you dude , that helped.

Comment: @Chrissisbeast No problem! If the answer works for you then please do mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.

For the `makeline()` function, just remove `\n` so it looks like this:

```
function makeLine(length) {
    var line = "";
    for (var j = 1; j <= length; j++) {
        line += "* ";
    }
    return line
}
```

For `buildTriange()` you have a few issues: 1) `var x = makeLine(1);` means that `x` will always be equal to `*`, because that is was `makeLine(1)` will return; 2) the `return` statement makes `x++` unreachable.

Consider this:

```
function buildTriangle(widest) {
  var output = '';
  var x = 1;
  while(x <= widest){
    output += makeLine(x) + '<br>';
    x++
  }
```

Now, it build an `output`. The `x` variable is a counter. While `x` is `1`  it will add to the `output` the result of `makeLine(1) + '<br>'`, then it will increase by 1 and run again until the value of `x` is the same as `widest`. Then it will return `output`.

Since `document.write()` writes html and not plain text. You have to use the line break, not a newline.

Comment: Thanks for the fast anwer!